# Display Country List with bootstrap-formhelpers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with boostrap-from helpers, when I renderer the page It doesn't show flags . 
I don't know if I can use this lib inside a grid (ig Grid of Ignite), if not which alternative should I use?

```
<div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">spartoo</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <span class="bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></span>
      </div>
   </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is webpack doesn't include this file when build the source